# How to configure the Kubernetes plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-eks

I have Jenkins Master running on an EC2 in AWS.  I then created a pipeline in EKS.  Both the Jenkins Master and the pipeline are running in the same VPC.  It is from the Jenkins Master that I create the EKS cluster via the CLi.

The EKS cluster is configured for clusterEndpoints: privateAccess: true and privateNetworking: true.  (I did not do privateCluster: enabled: true).

My problem is I am trying to setup the Kubernetes plugin in Jenkins and I am having issues figuring out some things.  The URL is simple.  But where do I get "Kubernetes server certificate key" I do not think its the certificate-authority-data from the .kube/config file.  Lastly, how do I setup the credentials?  I am using an IAM role on the Jenkins Master EC2 to login to the EKS Cluster.  I know I can use the aws cli to configure the token but how do I do that and how to I tell Jenkins about it.